# Reduce image size without changing the dimensions programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone

Does any one how to reduce image size without changing the dimensions of that image programmaticallyin iphone?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have a UIImage by itself or in a UIImageView?

Comment: i have a UIImage, which I am selecting from the iPhone photo album.

Answer (score 0):

// There is 3 way that were known to me.
//   1. Use just resize

```
    UIImageView *iView = ...;
    CGRect orgFrame = iView.frame;
    iView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    iView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(orgFrame), CGRectGetMinY(orgFrame),
                             CGRectGetWidth(orgFrame)*.5, CGRectGetHeight(orgFrame)*.5);
```

//   2. Use affineTransform for just display.
//      It use 3x3 matrix for scaling.
//      UIView has

```
@property(nonatomic) CGAffineTransform transform
```

//      Usage:

```
    UIImageView *iView = ...;
    iView.transform = CGAffineTransform(.5f, .5f);
    // ==> will display 1/2 size view.
```

//    3. Use CALayer renderInContext: for get reduced Image

```
    UIImage *sourceImage = ...;
    CGSize *reducedSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(sourceImage.frame)*.5f, CGRectGetHeight(sourceImage.frame)*.5f);
    UIImage *reducedImage; {
        UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView initWithImage:sourceImage];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(reducedSize);
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(.5f, .5f);
        [imageView renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

        reduceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have an UIImage, which i am getting from the iPhone photo album and not the UIImageView.